# mysql query "Invalid use of group function"

Tags: mysql, database, group-by

I have query like this

```
SELECT id_order_history,
       ( MAX(DATE(date_add)) - MIN(DATE(date_add))) AS selisih 
FROM ps_order_history 
WHERE id_order_state IN ('2', '48', '49', '50') 
      AND MONTH (date_add) = '05' 
      AND YEAR (date_add) = '2016' 
      AND (MAX(DATE(date_add)) - MIN(DATE(date_add)) > 5)
GROUP BY id_order
```

and it has an issue in

```
AND (MAX(DATE(date_add)) - MIN(DATE(date_add)) > 5)
```

How to solve it ?

Comment: use a `group by having` with selisih>5 and ditch the faulty aggregate functions from the where clause. See http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-having.aspx . Also the group by at the end does not specify a non-aggregate column shown on line 2

Comment: big thanks . it works correctly

Comment: No problem. Perhaps share your final work as a self-answer below.